# Using alias in insert statement

Tags: .net, sql, postgresql

I'm a SQL newbie having used ORMs most of the time. I am having trouble with aliases in the following query:

```
command.CommandText = @"
    INSERT INTO permissions (userid, remoteid)
        SELECT userid as uid, :remoteid as rid
        FROM users
        WHERE companyid = :companyid
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM permissions
                WHERE userid = uid
                AND remoteid = rid
            )";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyid", companyId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("remoteid", resourceId);
```

When the query executes, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 42703: column "uid" does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong? Are aliases supposed to be used like this and can they be used in an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: if you remove the aliases does the query work?

Comment: I need to be able to reference the `uid` in the where clause of the inner most select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
command.CommandText = @"
    INSERT INTO permissions (userid, remoteid)
        SELECT userid, :remoteid as rid
        FROM users uid
        WHERE companyid = :companyid
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM permissions
                WHERE userid = uid.userid
                AND remoteid = rid
            )";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyid", companyId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("remoteid", resourceId);
```

Comment: Yes, found that this work after asking the question. I also removed the `rid` alias and replaced it with the :remoteid parameter and renamed `uid` to `u1`